# handling json properties with name containing @ symbol

Tags: javascript, json, polymer-3.x, xml-to-json

I need to update a UI to polymer 3 and the received data is converted from XML to json before it reached the client.

on the client side, I am using Polymer3 template to pass the values to underlying polymer elements.

as the XML is storing the values in the attributes, My json comes back as follows.

```
{
    @type: "filter",
    @target: "somevalue1",
    @operator: "=",
    @value: "4458"
},
{
    @op: "Or",
    @type: "filter",
    @target: "somevalue2",
    @operator:  "=",
    @value: "4828"
},
{
    @op: "Or",
    @type: "filter",
    @target: "somevalue3",
    @operator: "=",
    @value: "2428"
}
```

now, when I pass this property into my polymer 3 template as with indexing, it considers the whole thing as text and displays on the screen.

```
{{item['@op']}}
```

is displayed on the screen as is. Also, I cannot use it as follows

```
{{item.@op}}
```

I do not know if @ is considered as code but the whole text incuding the parenthesis {{}} is displayed on the screen.

How to handle these properties.

I cannot convert it into another readable object because the UI is already taking time to render due to the <\vaadin-select> and the json is going to repeat itself inside it nested.

Comment: I am not sure how polymer interpolation works, but`item['@op']` is valid syntax to access an object property. [A comment from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534940/polymer-access-polymer-element-objects) suggests you to listen to `polymer-ready` event. Perhaps, that's what you're missing?

Comment: item['@op'] might not work in dom-repeat but Works in handleResponse function()... Try to assign response obj value to this., this.opVal= item['@op'] .... And render html., Bind value ... [[opVal]]

Comment: @shabarinath was right. I had to convert my component to LitElement so that I can handle it in the DOM template.

Comment: @HariKrishnaGaddipati ., perhaps can you upvote my comment or can you accept my answer

Comment: @shabarinath, you should repost your comment as an answer so people can spot it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Reposting my comment as answer for better view

`item['@op']` might not work in `dom-repeat` but Works in `handleResponse function()`

Try to assign response obj value to `this`,

i.e. `this.opVal= item['@op']` and in `render` html., Bind value as `[[opVal]]`